# youtube-dl rate limit download speed and auto resume download

Tags: shell, ubuntu, video, youtube, youtube-dl

I am using a shell script for video conversion.

this is the shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
#downloading video
youtube-dl www.someurl.com
#video conversion operations
```

Due to bandwidth issues, I have to lower the download speed. how do I limit the speed of video that is being downloaded from youtube-dl?
and how to make a youtube-dl auto-resume when my laptop wakes up from sleep? youtube-dl stops download when laptop sleeps and doesn't auto restart downloading even though my laptop is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use -r option to limit the speed. For example

```
youtube-dl -r 20K www.someurl.com
```

This will limit the speed to 20K. Note that speed is specified in bytes per second.

Answer (score 23):

I hope my answer is not too late, but in case of those that might still need it,

**Download resume :**

the `-c, --continue` Force resume of partially downloaded files.
By default, youtube-dl will resume downloads if possible.

```
youtube-dl  -c  www.someurl.com
```

**Limit download speed:**

the `-r, --rate-limit` LIMIT Maximum download rate in bytes per second                            (e.g. 50K or 4.2M)

```
youtube-dl  --rate-limit 20k  www.someurl.com
```

**OR**

```
youtube-dl  -r 20k  www.someurl.com
```

**SOURCE:** https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl