# Interval option when downloading HLS format videos published on Internet sites using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to download HLS format video as mp4 using ffmpeg.

I don't want to bother the server side due to excessive requests, so I want to create an interval for ts file acquisition.

When I actually run ffmpeg, I sometimes get an HTTP 429 error as shown below.

In addition, it looked like there are no good options in ffmpeg.

```
[https @ 000001bfef570100] Opening 'https://～/ts/9.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001bfeef31140] HTTP error 429 Too Many Requests
[hls @ 000001bfee6be200] keepalive request failed for 'https://～/ts/9.ts' with error: 'Server returned 4XX Client Error, but not one of 40{0,1,3,4}' when opening url, retrying with new connection
[https @ 000001bfef570100] Opening 'https://～/ts/9.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001bfef570100] Opening 'https://～/ts/10.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001bfef570100] Opening 'https://～/ts/11.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001bfef570100] Opening 'https://～/ts/12.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001bfef570100] Opening 'https://～/ts/13.ts' for reading
[https @ 000001bfeef31140] HTTP error 429 Too Many Requests
[hls @ 000001bfee6be200] keepalive request failed for 'https://～/ts/13.ts' with error: 'Server returned 4XX Client Error, but not one of 40{0,1,3,4}' when opening url, retrying with new connection
[https @ 000001bfef570100] Opening 'https://～/ts/13.ts' for reading
…
```

Can you come up with any good way?

I'm not good at English, so I may not be able to respond well. sorry.
This post was written by Google Translate.

Answer (score 1):

## Disable multiple HTTP connections

The [HLS demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1) has the option `-http_multiple`:

> Use multiple HTTP connections for fetching segments (default auto)

Disabling multiple HTTP connections may help (but probably will not help): `ffmpeg -http_multiple 0 -i https://...`

I do not see any useful options for the [HTTP protocol](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#http).

## Rate limit

You could try limiting the download speed with a "bandwidth shaper" or rate limiting tool. Example using `trickle` to run `ffmpeg` limiting the download capacity to 50 KB/s:

```
 trickle -d 50 ffmpeg ...
```

Or if you can use youtube-dl on the web site then you can limit the rate. See [youtube-dl rate limit download speed and auto resume download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998711/youtube-dl-rate-limit-download-speed-and-auto-resume-download).

## manual

Download the M3U8 file and manually download each `.ts` file listed in the M3U8 file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable persistent connection in ffmpeg via `-http_persistent 0`